# Changes is wagtail model don't show in admin

Tags: django, postgresql, wagtail

I have a brand new wagtail install and when I make changes in the HomePage class e.g.

```
class HomePage(Page):
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('body', classname="full"),
    ]
```

The admin has only one field - Title and body is missing.

The migrations are running correctly.
The new fields are showing in the database. 
My user is superuser in postgres.
I've tried to create a new Page model and it doesn't show, in the admin too.

I am running two projects on the same VPS with one postgres instance and two postgres users.

What might be wrong here?

Comment: Did you try to create `home_page.html` template? Does it renders?

Comment: Yes it renders and shows the title variable correctly when updated in the backend. The admin doesn't show the fields that I add. But they are available in the db.

Comment: It was a problem with postgres user permissions. I have changed the user owner of the database and it worked. So without the permissions it was writing but wasn't reading.